# Why GraphQL doesn't work on GatsbyJS layouts?

Tags: layout, graphql, gatsby

I want to query some data on my layout but **{console.log(data)}** returns **undefined**. It means my query doesn't work.

My **layouts/index.js** file:

```
import React from "react";
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Slider from "../components/Slider";
import {graphql} from "gatsby";

class DefaultLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const {data} = this.props

        return (
            <div className='container-fluid'>
                <Header/>

                {console.log(data)}
                {console.log(data)}
                {console.log(data)}

                <div className="row rtl">
                    <div className="col routeContainer">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col slider"><Slider/></div>
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        )}}
export default DefaultLayout
export const pageQuery = graphql`
      query {
         site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            subtitle
          }
        }
      }
    `
```

why so?!

*Using react 16.3.2 and gatsby next.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use StaticQuery. Your layout file is just a normal React component now.

https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/migrating-from-v1-to-v2/#remove-or-refactor-layout-components